# App force closes when google+ is not installed

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

My requirement is to share on Social networking sites. So, I have already done with Facebook and Twitter. But I am stuck with `Google+`. I have the following code to share on `Google+`, but the app `forcecloses` when I start activity. This occurs only when the `Google+ app` isn't installed on device already. I know this sharing intent requires the Google+ already installed to start the activity.

Now what I need to do is at least to inform the user that the `google+` sharing requires already installed `google+ app` through dialog or toast instead of getting force closed (If possible by clicking on ok on the dialog should redirect to the google+ on google play). If the google+ app is installed already it goes as usual.

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
             .setText("Hello there! This is a pic of the lazy cat")
             .setType("image/jpeg")
             .setStream(Uri.parse(path))
             .getIntent()
             .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
 startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the logcat and use a debugger. Most probably an unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: @Axel It gives ActivityNotFound Exception as it is unable to find the activity on the device that I specified. Because the google+ isn't installed. Please read my question and suggest.

Comment: Before ShareIntent make a check if g+ is installed. If so then execute your Intent. If No, inform user..

Comment: You can use GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp to easily check if the user has Google+ installed and react on it accordingly https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/GooglePlusUtil.html Also see https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#frequently_asked_questions

Comment: I am unable to import this package. It shows error. com.google.android.gms.plus.GooglePlusUtil; Seems I am missing some library files. Please suggest.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that, you need the Google Play Services SDK enabled and include <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib in your project: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Thanks gonna check it.

Comment: @Scarygami Why your answer isn't there now? I accepted it too. Strange that was deleted and the comments are added to the question.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**
The answer below is outdated. You can now check if the Google+ app is installed through the Google Play Services library (available through the Android SDK). See [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for information how to add it to your project.

Example:

```
int errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(mContext);
if (errorCode != GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS) {
  //Google+ is either not present or another error occured, show the error dialog
  GooglePlusUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
}
else{
  //Your Google+ related code here
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

You can create some sort of check to see if the Google+ app is installed:

```
public void loadGooglePlus()
{
    if(isGooglePlusInstalled())
    {
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
               .setText("Hello there! This is a pic of the lazy cat")
               .setType("image/jpeg")
               .setStream(Uri.parse(path))
               .getIntent()
               .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
       startActivity(shareIntent);
   }
   else{
      //Notify user
   }
}

public boolean isGooglePlusInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.plus", 0 );
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be good. Gonna try it. But is it possible to redirect the user to google+ on google play on his play store app if he clicks on okay button when he doesn't have google+ already installed?

Comment: To do this use the following code:

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus"));

startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: Thanks, you were of great help and the other answer worked api wise and it gives me ready-made alert dialog which redirects to google+app by pressing on get google+ button of that dialog.+1

Comment: Or use play services: [`GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/GooglePlusUtil.html#checkGooglePlusApp(android.content.Context))