# Catch Unsupported Action

Tags: java, android

At one point, my app needs to open an email client.

I send an intent to open it and everything works well.

But when the user doesn't have an email client installed, they get the "Unsupported action" error message.

Is there a way to catch when a user gets that error so that I can give them a dialog that points them to install gmail?

Comment: maybe you can use this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166376/app-force-closes-when-google-is-not-installed

Comment: Genius. I'll check to see if an email client is installed instead of checking if they get the error. Thanks. How do I set a comment as an answer?

Comment: This also happens if the user has an email client installed but hasn't set up an email address.

Answer (score 1):

I think this only happens on the official Android emulators; for some reason, they resolve the activity to the `com.android.fallback.Fallback` activity, which shows this cryptic message.

You can catch this scenario by running this code:

```
ComponentName emailApp = intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager());
ComponentName unsupportedAction = ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.fallback/.Fallback");
boolean hasEmailApp = emailApp != null && !emailApp.equals(unsupportedAction);
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email });
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Delivery Confirmation");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailcontent + "\n\n\n" + sign);
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail"));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    //Here you can show alerts
                }
```

Comment: Nope, tried that. ActivityNotFoundException apparently does not include the "unsupported action" error.

Comment: Then apparently you have to check for whether app is installed or not. Apparently Vitaly Menchikovsky has the answer in comments